LaserScan definition detail question
as a developer/tester of a sensor node, I wonder if there is any more detailed definition of fields in a LaserScan message? For example, the angle_min and angle_max are named "min" and "max" but then documented(*) as "start" and "end" angle (which can make quite a difference for a sensor scanning 360° in different directions).
I assume that actually "start" (corresponding to "first") and "end" (= "last") are meant,  and( for example) end angle is allowed to be numerically smaller than start angle? Is expected angular range in these data from 0 to 2pi or from -pi to pi or ...?
Which leads to a second question. Measurements are probably expected to appear in ranges[] and intensities[] in chronological order? So "angle_increment" can be negative (if sensor rotates in other direction)? Or "time_increment"?
Thanks for clarification or pointers to other documentation in advance!
Kolja

the only documentation I know of is https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/p/sensor_msgs/interfaces/msg/LaserScan.html ...


After 10 days with no further comment, it seems there is no more detailed specification than what already has been quoted and linked to.
It appears to me that `LaserScan message simply is not meant to be used for output from sensors that rotate clockwise or do output where the measurement at -180° appears somewhere in the middle of the data.
Although the laser_geometry algorithms (e.g. for LaserScan to Pointcloud transformation) seem to be able handle negative angle_increment and time_increment correctly, other potential LaserScan receivers probably cannot.
Thanks
Kolja

LaserScan msg:
std_msgs/Header header # timestamp in the header is the acquisition time of
                             # the first ray in the scan.
                             #
                             # in frame frame_id, angles are measured around
                             # the positive Z axis (counterclockwise, if Z is up)
                             # with zero angle being forward along the x axis

float32 angle_min            # start angle of the scan [rad]
float32 angle_max            # end angle of the scan [rad]
float32 angle_increment      # angular distance between measurements [rad]

float32 time_increment       # time between measurements [seconds] - if your scanner
                             # is moving, this will be used in interpolating position
                             # of 3d points
float32 scan_time            # time between scans [seconds]

float32 range_min            # minimum range value [m]
float32 range_max            # maximum range value [m]

float32[] ranges             # range data [m]
                             # (Note: values < range_min or > range_max should be discarded)
float32[] intensities        # intensity data [device-specific units].  If your
                             # device does not provide intensities, please leave
                             # the array empty.

It doesn't have to be 360 degree...
When you set angle_min to 0.0 and angle_max to 1.57, It will only see 90 degree angle like in this picture:

When you set angle_min to 0.0 and angle_max to 3.14, It will only see 180 degree angle like in this picture:

Or you can also set like this:
angle_min: -3.14
angle_max: 0

But be careful, when you change start and end point, you're also changing the order of the range data. For example in first image range[0] is the front of the robot but in the last image range[last_index] is the front of the robot.

Where do I find the definition of "front of the robot = 0°"? What if the sensor physically rotates in the other direction and measures towards mathematically decreasing angles? What if the scan data produced by the sensor describes 360° but starts at some arbitrary angle, e.g. -75° ??

Does "first ray in the scan" refer to the first in time (then angle_increment would have to be negative in case of clockwise scanner rotation) or just the first in ranges[] (then time_increment could be negative while angle_increment is positive)

1- If you want ranges[0] to be 0°, then you can set angle_min to 0.0.
2- If you want to start with -75°, then you need to set angle_min to -1.28. And if you do this, your ranges will start at this angle. It means your ranges[0] will point at this angle.

Hi, thanks for your attempt to answer my question, but it is mainly about the implications of measurement starting at an arbitrary angle and with arbitrary direction of rotation, which is a capability of the sensor for which I'm developing a driver. Computing some angle_min is trivial. But how about angle_max and sign of angle_increment and time_increment then.

A more concrete question: What are the correct (by some spec) values if there are 360 measurements, with the first one pointing towards -75° and the sensor rotating counter-clockwise? angle_min=-1.31, angle_increment=-0.017, angle_max=-1.33?

Sorry I meant the clockwise case

And a full 360° output (consisting of 360 values taken after 1° rotation each).

It appears to me that LaserScan message simply is not meant to be used for output from sensors that rotate clockwise or do output where the measurement at -180° is somewhere in the middle of the data. Although the LaserScanToPointCloud algorithms seem to be able to cope with any negative angle_increment and time_increment, but I suspect that many potential LaserScan receivers are not.
